# is there omniauth code/plugin for facebook that i can put straight into my ruby on rails site?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am making a social network on the teamtreehouse.com course in ruby on rails.

However, on the course they do not add a 'sign in with facebook' feature.

Is there any code i can put straight in so it will work? or a plugin type thing?

I tried to follow [this course](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) but i didn't really understand it.

ession["

Comment: Having looked at the link, it's a blow by blow instruction on what to do. I think you'll need to be a bit more precise as to what you've tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: @Iain I got up to this bit After the controller is defined, we need to implement the find_for_facebook_oauth method in our model (e.g. app/models/user.rb) but then didn't get when it said that it would randomly generate a new facebook account if the user didn't have one. How do i make it not do that?

Comment: Ah. What it's doing there is saying "has this user logged in to the site via facebook before?" I so, get the user from the database. If not, create a new user account using the auth hash that omniauth gives us (which will contain all the info given by facebook). That's all. I'm not sure why the method generates a random password? Perhaps because the password field has been set to disallow nulls, and so they fill it with a random string. I would never do that, just don't have a password field and use OmniAuth::Identity instead for "local" users. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a great [RailsCast by Ryan Bates  on logging in with Facebook](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) that should explain most everything you need.

(Yes, you do need to get a special developer token from Facebook).

Then, pony up for the Pro subscription for $9 -- writing Rails without RailsCasts is inconceivable to me :-)